# Error loading multiple tables in Qlik Sense

Tags: concatenation, multiple-tables, qliksense

I'm pulling in three tables into Qlik Sense, of which two are basically same tables with one filter difference (more than 4 counts, less than 4 counts) that I load with adding new filter field, as such:

```
Cohort1: 

Load

*
, 'LessThan4' as Cohort;

Cohort2: 

Load

*
, 'MoreThan4' as Cohort;
```

I do so because I need `Cohort` to be my filter for the entire app.

Then I have the third table, that is separate data that I need to outer join. All three tables have same `id` field that should tie each other, but I can't figure out right way to join them. I thought all three tables having same `id` field (named same) should be auto-concatenated, but it didn't. I've only done concatenating two tables, but to force concatenate all three tables, what is the right code?

Answer (score 1):

Qlik will automatically `link` the tables having a common fields (named the same). This `link` will act as `join` and the result will be multiple tables. `Concatenate` will result in multiple tables being append to one another and the final result will be one table.

If you want to have one table will all the records in it have a look into [Concatenating tables](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/April2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/LoadData/concatenate-tables.htm) documentation

The code below will show you how to perform force contatenation:

```
Table1:
  Field1, 
  Field2
From my-data.qvd;

Concatenate(Table1)

Table2:
  Field1, 
  Field3
From my-data1.qvd;
```

The result table will have 3 fields: `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`

Side note: Qlik will auto-concatenate tables having **exactly the same** set of fields. To avoid this have a look at the [NoConcatenate](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/April2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/NoConcatenate.htm) statement